# cubic diophantine equations $x^3+11y^3=1$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

Many books solve this equation looking roots of $x^3-11$ in $\mathbb{Q}_{19}$. But there is a point not so clear.
These roots correspond to $$a_1=-2+8*19 \pmod{19^2} \\ a_2=-3+5*19 \pmod{19^2}\\
a_3=5+6*19 \pmod{19^2}.$$
Now we know $\epsilon=1+4\theta-2\theta^2$ is fundamental unit ($\theta=11^{1/3}$) and then every book says these correspond to 3 embeddings of $\epsilon$ and without calculation these are $$v_1=4 \pmod{19^2} \\ v_2=9+2*19 \pmod{19^2} \\ v_3=9+16*19 \pmod{19^2}$$
I made calculation by me but i'm not sure i used correct embeddings (for me  they correspond  to $v_i=1+4a_i-2a_i^2$ as element of $\mathbb{Q}_{19}$.
But the results are wrong. What are these embeddings? Thanks.

Comment: Should $\mathbb{Q}_{19}$ be $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$?

Comment: @robjohn Because those zeros are in the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{Z}$ they are, indeed, in $\Bbb{Z}_{19}$. But that's a subset of $\Bbb{Q}_{19}$, so I don't think it makes a difference for the rest of the question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: both were mentioned in the question, now I see that only $\mathbb{Q}_{19}$ is.

Comment: @robjohn I missed the edit! In the earlier edition $\Bbb{Z}_{19}$ made an appearance. Sorry!

Comment: I made the edit only for coerence, actually we find solution in $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ but the embedding is in $\mathbb{Q}_{19}$

Comment: Matvey, what is wrong with the results? I think I got the same. Checking one more time...

Comment: My results are$ v_1=4+19 \\ v_2=9+4*19 \\v_3=9-19  \pmod{19^2}$

Comment: $a_1\equiv150\pmod{19^2}$, so
$$v_1=1+4\cdot150-2\cdot150^2=-44399\equiv4\pmod{19^2}?$$

Comment: But there are some subtleties in Hensel lifting the zeros, because $9$ is a double root of the minimal polynomial $x^3-3x^2+267x-1$ of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Talk more tomorrow. I'm about to doze off. G'night!

Comment: Yes now understand the mistake, a part of calculation i used mod 19, sorry, the embedding are correct! Thanks you very much!!